# Invoke a One Midlet from another Midlet

Tags: java-me, barcode-scanner, midlet

I’m working on J2ME Barcode Scanner using Zxing1.7 Library since  1.7 is the latest version which supports J2ME.

Since barcode functionality is already present as part of this Zxing, I need to call ZxingMidlet.java from my component Midlet.

As I’m very new to J2ME, I’m not getting how to invoke a ZxingMidlet from another Midlet.
Please provide your input/support If anyone has already worked on J2ME/has any experience on this.

It will be of great help to me.

Regards,
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

The [ZXingMIDlet.java](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/javame/src/com/google/zxing/client/j2me/ZXingMIDlet.java?r=1302) is just an example of how to use their library. You should copy the parts of the code you need into your own project, instead of trying to start another midlet from your midlet.